# Reading a tab-separated file in Java

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I have the following piece of code to read a tab-separated file in Java:

```
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
  if (str.trim().length() == 0) {
          continue;
  }

  String[] values = str.split("\\t");

  System.out.println("Printing file content:");
  System.out.println("First field" + values[0] + "Next field" +  values[1]);
}
```

But it's printing 1 instead of the file content. What is wrong here?
A line from the sample file reads as follow:

```
{Amy Grant}{/m/0n8vzn2}{...}
```

Comment: What's the string text you're splitting?

Comment: Could you please add an example file?

Comment: There are lots of TSV and CSV parser libraries around - I would strongly advise you to use one of them instead of rolling your own.

Comment: You can write just `\t`.

Comment: Here is a sample line: Amy Grahm /m/010h  /m/0djb3s9,/m/0crr_xl,/m/0crtkkm,/m/0crxm5d

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's not working either.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(values));`

Comment: @EshaGhosh Are you sure, the file is tab-separated?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: can you please point me to some library?

Comment: @EshaGhosh Can you show us where the tabs are using the original question?  They will not show up in a comment.

Comment: @EshaGhosh I suspect your problem will not be solved by using a different library.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: This works! But I need to access the fields separately. COuld you plesae tell me what is wring in my code?

Comment: @EshaGhosh What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Try `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(values))`;
>
> This works! But I need to access the fields separately. Could you plesae tell me what is wring in my code?

I suspect you are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The error you are getting is important and you can't hope to solve the problem if you ignore it.

This would mean you have only one field set.

```
String[] values = str.split("\\t", -1); // don't truncate empty fields

System.out.println("Printing file content:");
System.out.println("First field" + values[0] + 
   (values.length > 1 ? ", Next field" +  values[1] : " there is no second field"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That *Don't truncate empty fields* helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Write `\t` instead of `\\t`. That would be more of what you want

```
String[] values = str.split("\t");
```

I'm using http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/ in some of my projects, and it gets the job done quite well.

Comment: Aren't they equivalent? Wouldn't \\ resolve to a \ leaving you with a \t?

Comment: That means split on the two characters `\t` not on a tab.

Comment: "\" is an error. "\t" is a special character, TAB. "\\t" is "\t", but not a TAb.