# Word Phrases in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am currently doing a project in my Java class which involves scanning a text file and then breaking each line up with java regular expressions.  An example of the one of the lines in the text file is shown below:

[image: Picture of text]

I have been trying to break this up so that I can get the word phases like "Ultra Liquid Bleach" and "Mountain Fresh" but not the white spaces in between.  My current code that I have so far is:

```
([\\w]+|[ ]?)\\b
```

and I cannot get any farther than that.  The first two words vary in number of words so any expression that targets a specific number of words will not work.  Am I on the right track or is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: How can a computer know that you want `Ultra Liquid Bleach`/`Mountain Fresh` as opposed to `Ultra Liquid`/`Bleach Mountain Fresh` if you don't know how many words will come and have provided no other rules for parsing?

Comment: Why "Ultra Liquid Bleach" and "Mountain Fresh" are two phrases? What counts as a phrase?

Comment: What separates your columns?

Comment: Maybe this is a tsv? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575308/read-a-file-separated-by-tab-and-put-the-words-in-an-arraylist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331696/reading-tab-delimited-textfile-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361650/reading-a-tab-separated-file-in-java What about `(.*?)(?:\t|$)` assuming is tsv?

Answer (score 0):

You used an image rather than providing us a text-based example, but this should work for you assuming "word phrases" are always separated by 3+ spaces and you would never expect tabs or 3+ spaces within an individual "word phrase"

### Assumed input:

```
Disinfecting Wipes        Lemon Fresh                       35 pkg      3.39
Ultra Liquid Bleach       Mountain Fresh                    96 oz       2.39
FF & LS Broth             Chicken                           32 oz       2.99
```

### Regex:

```
\b(\S+(?:  ?\S+)*)\b
```

Explanation (see also: [more detail and output of run against assumed input](https://regex101.com/r/cysp8b/1)):

- `\b`: Word boundary (zero-width marker between a word char (`\w`) and a non-word char (`\W`)
- `(`: Matching group starts here

  - `\S+`: One or more non-space characters
  - `(?:`: Non-matching group starts here

    - `?`: A literal space and then 0 or 1 literal spaces
    - `\S+`: One or more non-space characters
  - `)*`: This non-matching group may be present zero or more times
- `)`: end of matching group
- `\b`: Word boundary